# Javascript dynamic IF regex condition without eval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, filtering, eval

I'm adding multi-group checkbox filtering (multiple unordered lists of checkboxes) to a web app and I'm stuck trying to get around using eval (or maybe I shouldn't worry in this case?). Basically, the data is called with one AJAX call, I'm storing that in an array of objects and I'm doing live filtering without making additional AJAX calls. When the checkboxes are checked I'm using .match() and I'm basically creating the regular expression as string values in an array (k is the category object property, such as category1):

```
filterArgs.push("(data['" + k + "'].join(', ').match(/" + filters[k].join('') + ".+/))");
```

The filters array is set up in a loop above that and it looks like this (v is the actual string value - the category name):

```
filters[k][z] = '(?=.*\\b' + v[z] + '\\b)';
```

Then I'm joining the filterArgs:

```
return filterArgs.join(' && ');
```

filterArgs is currently passed to an if statement condition with eval like this:

```
if(eval(filter_setup())){
```

So, if that if statement is true, the correct object from the main data array is included in the filtered set of data. I'm probably going to switch to jQuery's $.grep instead of that if statement but I still run into the same eval issue. Is there any other way to build a dynamic regular expression? It's working fine with eval but I've read all the articles saying how "evil" it is. The if statement condition ends up looking like the following (2 boxes checked in the first group and 1 in another group):

```
(data['type'].join(', ').match(/(?=.*\bRestaurant\b)(?=.*\bBar\b).+/)) && (data['state'].join(', ').match(/(?=.*\bWashington\b).+/))
```

Comment: This definitely sounds like an XY problem. You can build dynamic regex with the built-in RegExp constructor.

Comment: ^^ my thoughts exactly, pass the string directly to RegExp

Comment: Don't forget to escape `()[]{}\*+^$.?` in the user's input.

Comment: And yeah, the filterArgs you're building is not the way to go; just run the ifs one at a time in the loop; if any return false, return false overall. No eval needed. eval is never excusable, btw, unless you really *really* know what you're doing and you're solving one of about 3 problems (and even in those cases it's often preferable to write your own interpreter instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `eval` as much as possible. In this case, it's definitely not necessary.

Store the `filter` object when needed and define something like this:

```
function checkFilters(data, filters) {
    for (var k in filters) {
        if (!(new RegExp(filters[k].join("")).test(data[k])))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
if (checkFilters(data, filters)) {
    ...
}
```

By the way, creating `RegExp` object using the constructor is expensive. If you need more speed, you can precompile the filters and keep them instead of an array of conditions:

```
filters[k] = new RegExp(filters[k].join(""));
```

Additionally, as Dave noted, depending on your data you may need to escape the filters:

```
filters[k][z] = '(?=.*\\b'
        + v[z].replace(/([\^\$\/\.\*\+\?\|\(\)\[\]\{\}\\])/g, "\\$1")
        + '\\b)';
```

Comment: Thanks. Escaping the filters was my next step so it's great that you also included it.

Comment: I was testing this a bit more and it actually isn't working the way I was hoping it would. With this method the filtering seems to only filter based on one of the filter groups. If filters from different groups are selected, it filters based on the first filter group only.

Comment: Ok, I think I have the issue I mentioned in the previous comment worked out. Instead of returning from the for loop I set a boolean variable above the loop to true, set it to false if the RegExp fails, then return the boolean if it's true after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing an expression, you can push a function:

```
 filterArgs.push(function(k){
   var re = new RegExp(filters[k].join('') + ".+");
   return function(data){
     return data[k].join(', ').match(re);
   }
 });
```

Now you can execute the functions instead of evaluating a string:

```
 for(var cond = true, i = 0; cond && i < filterArgs.length; i++) {
   cond &= filterArgs[i](data);
 }
```